# Material Design Lite Lists - how to access selected elements?

Tags: material-design, aurelia

I'm using Aurelia framework with Material Design Lite via plugin "aurelia-mdl-plugin".

I have the following markup:

```
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Name</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr repeat.for="s of items">
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">${s.name}</td>
            <td>${s.someothercol}</td>
            <td><a href="/import/${s._id}">View</a></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

This markup represents a list of items that are selectable - each of them gets a checkbox with ability to select + the list gets "select all" check box in the header.

The problem is that since this additional markup with checkboxes is generated by MDL I can't really bind to it.

If I had a checkbox manually inserted I would do something like:

`<input type="checkbox" checked.bind="s.IsChecked" />`

Is there any way to fix this?

PS> I don't think it's necessarily Aurelia specific. Most likely I would have the same problem in Angular or other library..

Answer (score 1):

The mdl team officially deprecated automatic checkbox insertion. So now you should write them down manually, which would solve your binding issue.

See this link: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/wiki/Deprecations#automatic-selection-checkboxes